# Can't save model in saved_model format when finetune bert model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, bert-language-model

When training the bert model, the weights are saved well, but the entire model is not saved.

After `model.fit`,
save model as `model.save_weights('bert_xxx.h5')` and `load_weights` works fine,
but since only weights are saved, the model frame must be loaded separately.

So I want to save the entire model at once.

---

However, the following error occurs.

[image]

[image]

---

The tensorflow version was **2.4**, and the bert code used **https://qiita.com/namakemono/items/4c779c9898028fc36ff3**

Why is only the weights saved and not the entire model?
And how can I save the whole model??

Comment: Do you ever try to save your trained model as a `pickle file` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72674510/1740577)? do you have an error with `pickle` too?

Comment: @I'mahdi yes, Pickle also has an error.

--------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects

Comment: Hi @Penguin_., please try using `model.save("model_name", save_format='tf')` to save the model and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.